# How to slice off bits from an integer

Tags: javascript, integer, bit-manipulation, bit

I could create a bitwise trie that just looks like this:

```
                      x
         _____________|___________
        |                         |
     ___●___                   ___□___
    |       |                 |       |
   _■      _○                _■       □_
  |       |                 |           |
 _■     __■__           ____●___        ○____
|      |     |         |        |            |
●      ●     □_        ●       _○_        ___□
               |              |   |      |
               ○              ●   ○    __■
                                      |
                                      ●
```

However, I would like to try something different. Instead of doing *binary* tries (bitwise tries) -- which are based on taking *1 bit at a time* and choosing the next 1 of 2 slots to visit -- I would like to use *2 bits at a time*, or *3 bits at a time*, etc. Using 2 bits at a time would create a trie that has 4 branches. Using 3 bits, it would have 8 branches. This would be nice to use to compact the trie a little bit.

So I'm wondering how to do that. How to take an integer and essentially slice off 2 or 3 or *n bits* at a time. So given an integer like this:

```
10010110
```

That is `150` in binary.

I would like to get let's say 2 bytes at a time, so:

```
10
01
01
10
```

That would mean I put it in slot 2, then 1, then 1, then 2. Or if I chose 4 bits, then:

```
1001
0110
```

That would put it in slot 9 then slot 6.

So the question is, how to implement a function sort of like this:

```
function sliceInteger(integer, start, length) {
  return integer[start..length]
}

var x = sliceInteger(150, 4, 4) // => 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use bitwise arithmetic:

```js
function sliceInteger(integer, start, length) {
  return (integer >> start) & ((1 << length) - 1);
}
console.log(sliceInteger(150, 4, 4));
```

**Edit**

I notice that in your question you are slicing right to left i.e. MSB to LSB, whereas the function I've written above slices left to right i.e. LSB to MSB, hence it returns 9 where your suggested result is 6. If that is the way you want to slice, you should use this function instead. Note that if you want to slice longer than 8-bit integers, you will need to change the `8` in the code appropriately.

```js
function sliceInteger(integer, start, length) {
  return (integer >> (8 - start - length)) & ((1 << length) - 1);
}
console.log(sliceInteger(150, 4, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert number to binary string and splice it then convert that to decimal number

```js
function sliceInteger(integer, start, length) {
  var binary = integer.toString(2)
  binary = binary.slice(start, start+length)
  return parseInt(binary, 2)
}

console.log(sliceInteger(150, 4, 4))
```